# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from.......failed to load external entity

Tags: php, soap

I want to get response from SOAP Service. and i always get error Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from.......failed to load external entity.
I try these script:

```
$wsdl='http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/xx/xxxx?wsdl';
$soapclient = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
    'login' => "xxx",
    'password' => "xxxx",
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8', 
    'verifypeer' => false, 
    'verifyhost' => false, 
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1, 
    'trace' => 1, 
    'exceptions' => 1, 
    "connection_timeout" => 180, 
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
));
$param=array('studentNumber'=>'0001');
$response = $soapclient->getStudentInfo($param);
var_dump($response);
```

Anyone have the solution please help me i am stuck with this error. I need help.

Comment: I would suggest that the WSDL file isn't available. Error message is pretty clear on that.

Comment: @miken32 so you mean i can't fetch data from WSDL in PHP?

Comment: You can if it's being served properly at the specified URL.

Comment: @miken32 How to know WSDL file isn't available?